# log4js npm error , log4js configuration

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, log4js-node

root@------:~# cd /home/bot
root@------:/home/bot# `node site.js`
/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:43
        throw new Error(`Problem with log4js configuration: (${util.inspect(this.candidate, { depth: 5 })})` +
        ^

Error: Problem with log4js configuration: ({ appenders:
   [ { type: 'console' },
     { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' } ] }) - must have a property "appenders" of type object.
    at tests.forEach (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:43:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Configuration.throwExceptionIf (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:41:11)
    at new Configuration (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:203:10)
    at Object.configure (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/log4js.js:205:12)
    at Object. (/home/bot/site.js:12:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

i use command `npm install log4j --save`

root@------:/home/bot# `npm install log4j --save`
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nave/installed/6.11.1/bin/node" "/root/.nave/installed/6.11.1/bin/npm" "install" "log4j" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/log4j
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'log4j' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/bot/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as u with the same script xD.
I found a solution!!!!!!!!!!!!!
U need to change thelog4js.configure in your site.js to this

> 

```
log4js.configure({
    appenders: {
        out: { type: 'console' },
        task: { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' }
    },
    categories: {
    default: { appenders: [ 'out' ], level: 'info' },
    task: { appenders: [ 'task' ], level: 'info' }
  }
});
```